# wso2-am https API

Tags: https, wso2, wso2-api-manager

Good day! I created an API and want to use https access to it, for example: https: // localhost: 8243 / ssl / 1.0. Tell me where is the certificate for this API for him?
And the second question is, can I replace it with my own certificate?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new keystore using a cert you have. Please check - https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/install-and-setup/setup/security/configuring-keystores/keystore-basics/creating-new-keystores/#creating-new-keystores

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in <certificate file>.crt -inkey <private>.key -name wso2carbon -certfile <additional certificate file> -out wso2.pfx

keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore wso2.pfx -srcstoretype pkcs12 -destkeystore wso2carbon.jks -deststoretype JKS
```

Then you can replace the existing wso2carbon.jks in repository/resources/security location.